# Unable to get proper 'key' value from JSON - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

My goal is to achieve table in the below format using AngularJS from the below sample nested JSON.

```
{
  "traits": ["Number of Observations","Observed Number of Exceptions","95-99", "95-95","99-95", "99-99"],
  "values": [
    {
      "AAAA1": {
        "Number of Observations": 252,
        "95-95": {
            "Test Statistic": -1.040531963428947,
            "P-Value": 0.85095358899764695,
            "Test Outcome": "p-value >=0.05"
        },

        "95-99": {
            "Test Statistic": 5.368809379876272,
            "P-Value": 3.9629067916102656e-08,
            "Test Outcome": "p-value <0.01"
        },

        "Observed Number of Exceptions": 9
      }
    },
    {
      "AAAA2": {
        "Number of Observations": 43,
       "95-99": {
            "Test Statistic": -1.040531963428947,
            "P-Value": 0.85095358899764695,
            "Test Outcome": "p-value >=0.05"
        },
        "95-95": {
            "Test Statistic": -0.46245865041286727,
            "P-Value": 0.67812377583172401,
            "Test Outcome": "p-value >=0.05"
        },

        "Observed Number of Exceptions": 7
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

There are two Objects under 'values' key which in turn will create two rows in the table. My problem in creating the table here with the JSON is, i need to loop through '95-95' Object, '95-99' Object etc and create '3' columns for each object. With this below code, i was able to create 3 columns under the '95-95' Object; but as you can see i hard-coded with '**AAAA1**' key value in `ng-repeat` .  ***At row level in table, i am looping with outer-most json;for 'td' creations looping through inner-most JSON object so unable to get middle-level Object key value.*** Is there any way where can i get it from any the key value 'AAAA1', 'AAAA2' which Object not in any `ng-repeat`.

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key,value) in Controller.values">

    <td class="text-center"  ng-repeat="(key1,value1) in value['AAAA1']['95-95']">
        {{value1}}                   
    </td>
```

As i could not achieve this, i am currently stuck with the below static code which is not very useful for me.

```
<td class="text-center"  ng-repeat="(key1,value1) in value">
       {{value1["95-95"]["Test Statistic"]}}                 
</td>

<td class="text-center" ng-repeat="(key1,value1) in value"> 
    {{value1["95-95"]["P-Value"]}}                   
</td>

<td class="text-center" ng-repeat="(key1,value1) in value">
    {{value1["95-95"]["Test Outcome"]}} 
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `value['AAAA1']['95-95']` must be an Array.

ng-Repeat works only with arrays :(

Comment: ng-repeat works with an object with this syntax : `(key, value) from object`

Comment: Key is the index

Comment: in an array yes. An array is "pretty much like" an object with the index as a key.

Comment: The object never worked for me in angular 1.x , I always had to wrap it in an array to make it work.

Comment: pretty weird it is supposed to work. It is even documented [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

Comment: I see, I reread it myself... it always ended with 'not an array' error... O.o

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid a directive or code in the controller you can do it like this :

```js
const myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('Ctrl', ($scope) => {
 $scope.values = 
  [
    {
      "AAAA1": {
        "Number of Observations": 252,
        "95-95": {
            "Test Statistic": -1.040531963428947,
            "P-Value": 0.85095358899764695,
            "Test Outcome": "p-value >=0.05"
        },

        "95-99": {
            "Test Statistic": 5.368809379876272,
            "P-Value": 3.9629067916102656e-08,
            "Test Outcome": "p-value <0.01"
        },

        "Observed Number of Exceptions": 9
      }
    },
    {
      "AAAA2": {
        "Number of Observations": 43,
       "95-99": {
            "Test Statistic": -1.040531963428947,
            "P-Value": 0.85095358899764695,
            "Test Outcome": "p-value >=0.05"
        },
        "95-95": {
            "Test Statistic": -0.46245865041286727,
            "P-Value": 0.67812377583172401,
            "Test Outcome": "p-value >=0.05"
        },

        "Observed Number of Exceptions": 7
      }
    }
  
  ]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <table ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <tbody ng-repeat="value in values">
      <tr ng-repeat="(name, objectAA) in value">
        <th ng-bind="name"></th>
        <td ng-repeat="(key, value) in objectAA['95-95']" ng-bind="value">
          
        </td>
        <td ng-repeat="(key, value) in objectAA['95-99']" ng-bind="value">
          
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

To avoid the statics '95-95' and '95-99' in the html you can extract them in the controller.

With specific code in the controller you can do it like this :

```js
const myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('Ctrl', ($scope) => {

  $scope.rows = []

 $scope.values = 
  [
    {
      "AAAA1": {
        "Number of Observations": 252,
        "95-95": {
            "Test Statistic": -1.040531963428947,
            "P-Value": 0.85095358899764695,
            "Test Outcome": "p-value >=0.05"
        },

        "95-99": {
            "Test Statistic": 5.368809379876272,
            "P-Value": 3.9629067916102656e-08,
            "Test Outcome": "p-value <0.01"
        },

        "Observed Number of Exceptions": 9
      }
    },
    {
      "AAAA2": {
        "Number of Observations": 43,
       "95-99": {
            "Test Statistic": -1.040531963428947,
            "P-Value": 0.85095358899764695,
            "Test Outcome": "p-value >=0.05"
        },
        "95-95": {
            "Test Statistic": -0.46245865041286727,
            "P-Value": 0.67812377583172401,
            "Test Outcome": "p-value >=0.05"
        },

        "Observed Number of Exceptions": 7
      }
    }
  
  ]
  
  $scope.values.forEach((value) => {
    Object.keys(value).forEach((name) => {
      $scope.rows.push({name: name, value: value[name]});
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <table ng-controller="Ctrl">
      <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
        <th ng-bind="row.name"></th>
        <td ng-repeat="(key, value) in row.value['95-95']" ng-bind="value">
          
        </td>
        <td ng-repeat="(key, value) in row.value['95-99']" ng-bind="value">
          
        </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: as per your snippet, it will create multiple tbody in the table.

Comment: Yes, but I don't see any other way without a custom directive

Comment: I just added a solution with code in the controller